# Replace dataframe multiple columns with id from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Pandas Dataframe **df1** as:

> ```
> ID | c1 | c2 | c3
> -----------------
> 1  | A  | B  | 32
> 2  | C  | D  | 34
> 3  | A  | B  | 11
> 4  | E  | F  | 3
> ```

And **df2**:

> ```
> ID | c1 | c2
> ------------
> 1  | A  | B
> 2  | C  | D
> 3  | E  | F
> ```

There is foreign key between **df1** and **df2** on columns (c1, c2). Join look like:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['c1','c2'], right_on = ['c1','c2'])
```

Result is:

> ```
> ID_x| c1 | c2 | c3 | ID_y
> -------------------------
> 1   | A  | B  | 32 | 1
> 2   | C  | D  | 34 | 2
> 3   | A  | B  | 11 | 1
> 4   | E  | F  | 3  | 3
> ```

I want to replace (c1,c2) in **df1** with **df2.id**.
Expected FINAL df1 is:

> ```
> ID| c3 | df2_id
> ---------------
> 1 | 32 | 1
> 2 | 34 | 2
> 3 | 11 | 1
> 4 | 3  | 3
> ```

In other words I want to add column 'df2_id' in df1(filled with df2.id value for this row) and drop columns (c1,c2)(they are not necessary anymore).

I have idea to do that by:

1. save result from **merge** in df1
2. drop unnecessary columns (c1,c2)
3. rename 'ID_y' to 'df2_id' and 'ID_x' to 'ID'

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could make a one liner out of your steps by making use of [`suffixes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) argument and `on` instead of `left_on, right_on` plus using *method chaining* with [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['c1','c2'], suffixes=['_1', '_2']).drop(['c1', 'c2'], axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
   ID_1  c3  ID_2
0     1  32     1
1     3  11     1
2     2  34     2
3     4   3     3
```

To make it exactly like OP's output:

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['c1','c2'], suffixes=['', '_2']).drop(['c1', 'c2'], axis=1).rename(columns={"id_2": "df2_id"})
```

Comment: Wow, cool! :) To be perfect I would only change suffixes=['_1', '_2'] to suffixes=['', '_2'] and add in the end .rename(columns={"id_2": "df2_id"})

Comment: Sure, added@MorticiaA.Addams